# enabling node wrangler Blender 2.8

Tags: node-editor

Well I am trying to make a project in blender. And im trying to enable my node wrangler if someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Node Wrangler* add-on is shipped with Blender and can be enabled in the preferences.

Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*).

[image: Preferences]

Select *Add-ons* in the preferences and search for "Node Wrangler". Enable *Node Wrangler* by clicking on the checkbox next to it.

[image: Add-ons]

Comment: Tnx for the help

Comment: @SilentAssasinGaming If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.